# Execution order of servlet listeners in web fragments and web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

Is there a way to specify the execution order of ServletContextListeners that are defined in web.xml and web-fragment.xml?

I have two listeners in my application:
The first is declared in the web-fragment.xml

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.example.RunFirst</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and a second one in web.xml of my Application

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.example.RunSecond</listener-class>
</listener>
```

additionally my web-fragment contains the following ordering element:

```
<ordering>
  <before>
    <others />
  </before>
</ordering>
```

but the RunSecond is still executed before RunFirst. Any idea how i can change this order?

Comment: In which order are defined your listeners in your web.xml?

Comment: the RunFirst listener is only defined in the web-fragment.xml of my fragment

Comment: And in which part of your web.xml you add this web-fragment?

Comment: I did not add the fragment in my web.xml (BTW: I did not know that this is possible). I just added the web-fragments.xml in the META-INF of my jar, and the listener is executed. Unfortunately to late.

Comment: Well, AFAIK the filters and listeners described in web.xml will be loaded and applied in the order they appear. From [Shing Wai Chan's Weblog](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment), seems like you can only determine the order of the processing of web-fragments, but the order of processing the elements configured in web.xml and web-fragment.xml s is vendor specific.

Comment: So if i want my RunFirst Listener to be executed first, i have to put all other listeners in web-fragments too?

Comment: Seems like that, or move your filter/listener to web.xml and before `RunSecond`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is not possible at all.

As stated in oracle docs: "The web.xml descriptor is always processed first."

What you could do is create another web-fragment.xml with your RunSecond listener and set the relative order between the fragments using "ordering".

Hope it helps.